# Randomly selecting albums, rather than songs, to fit on my iPod

Tags: ipod, foobar2000

With iTunes you can get a random list of songs synced on to your iPod until your device is full. I want to do this with Foobar2000 but have a random list of albums added until full.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it, but, provided your albums are stored as a collection of files within a single folder, you can do the following:

Create a playlist with the music you wish to choose from.
Select all songs (Ctrl-A)
Right click -> sort -> randomize
Right click -> File operations -> Copy to -> ...
Choose a folder to copy to (Ideally your player), tick "Copy entire source folder content" and start copying.
Choose "Skip" if prompted to deal with a file conflict.
If copying to player, you'll get an error when it's filled to capacity, otherwise stop when enough files are copied.